# Demonstrate the resolution of laplace inverses

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

demonstrate the resolution of laplace inverses, I got a slightly scary result, but I wanted to clear up a doubt.

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \dfrac{1}{s^2(s+2)} \right\} - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \dfrac{e^{-s}}{s^2(s+2)}\right\} - \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{e^{-s}}{s(s+2)}\right\} $

In the first inverse of Laplace, I set up a system using separation of attainment, obtaining a=-1/4, b=1/2, and c=1/4. getting, then, after the inverse of laplace, with the result equal to $\frac{1}{4}*4H(t) + \frac{1}{2}*t + \frac{1}{4} * e^{-2t}$

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? It seems nothing more than an exercise in partial fractions.

Comment: In the first inverse of Laplace, I set up a system using separation of attainment, obtaining a=-1/4, b=1/2, and c=1/4. getting, then, after the inverse of laplace, with the result equal to $\frac{1}{4}*4H(t) + \frac{1}{2}*t + \frac{1}{4} * e^{-2t}$

Comment: The presence of $e^{-s}$ in the second and third terms means you should be ending up with $H(t-1)$ showing up, not just $H(t)$. (Note that $H(t)=1$ for $t\geq 0$, which is always true when working with the Laplace transform.)